# X11 Inside Qt How to click the mouse on top window

Tags: qt, mouseevent, x11

Building a Qt application that spawns another app and then clicks on it - the top window I think. Got it working on Windows with SendInput, now for the same idea on Linux I'm trying to use X11. Found lots of examples using XQueryPointer and XSendEvent. Odd loop looking through windows and subwindows I have no clue about. Anyway, it doesn't work and I have no idea which window the code is trying to target. Nobody talks about that in the examples.

Code runs, checks for errors and finds none. But clicks do not work. My click on mouse works instantly.

How do I figure out where clicks are going? And how do I find the top window or whatever I need to send clicks there?

Code is long, so I'll blog it and come back here with a reply with link to code routines.

App Output shows clicks are sent

[image]

Here's a blog post with the code:

https://windyweather.net/2019/04/09/x11-xsendevent-does-not-click-mouse/

Do Github Gists work here by the way? Anyway. Just discovered them and they are way cool. Work fine on wordpress.com. Who knew.

Don't need to use X11, it just seems easier than the uinput alternative that I saw before.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have beat my head against the wall trying to fix the QtShowRunner program that works on Windows to work on Linux. None of the methods have worked.

- Kernel uinput API calls never worked.
- Using the X11 XSendEvent to send either Mouse clicks or Key events didn’t work.

Finally I found a command called xdotool which does many X things including sending mouse clicks and key presses. Here’s a shell script that uses the xdotool to launch soffice impress to show a slideshow and then terminates the show and then exits the script.

[More details at my blog:](https://windyweather.net/2020/04/09/impress-show-runner-trivial-on-linux/)

[Script to run Slideshow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTa7C.png)